# Google Cloud Kubernetes Nginx Ingress hang on "Creating ingress"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

When creating an ingress resource in GCE using the Nginx ingress controller, the ingress resource is stuck on "Creating ingress". Any custom annotations appear to be lost, but I can access the URL defined by the ingress.

What could be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be because I was sending the annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
```

instead of

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1990, the Nginx controller only accepts strings containing "true" or "false". By sending boolean values, GCE was hanging.

Interestingly there were no errors indicating a problem, and I could access the ingress URL, which made debugging the problem quote painful.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same situation in GKE, just go to the console and click on "Services and Ingress" and click on the Ingress to see a possible error.

Mine was a misspelled service name.

I had to delete the Ingress and re-apply the ingress manifest (kubectl apply -f my-ingress.yaml)