# Deploy a Flask Service on Google Kontainer Engine

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask app to Google's Kubernetes Engine Cluster. I have created a deployment, service and ingress controller on the cluster.

> Notice:
>   I have taken a look at various other questions here like [Google Cloud Kubernetes Nginx Ingress hang on "Creating ingress"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072764/google-cloud-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-hang-on-creating-ingress)  it's specific to Nginx, so don't mark this as duplicate, please!

AND Here's the Service & Deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9080
    name: http
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: arycloud/flask-svc:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
```

and

> Here's the Ingress **YAML**:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: svc-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: myapp
    servicePort: 9080
```

It creates the myapp service and deployment in Kubernetes cluster on GKE but the Ingress controller hangs on `Creating ingress`.
Here's the screenshot:

> [image]

What's going to wrong here?